# How i can access Smartcard Reader from IIS

Tags: asp.net, smartcard

I could not access my smartcard reader from IIS.. but I access from my local IIS how can I solve this problem?

My platform is visual studio 2015 and Windows 8.1
 - I can access my smart card from local IIS which is visual studio IIS however When I publish my local IIS my code is not access to my smart card.

Thanks.

Comment: I don t want to use ActiveX, Silverlight... is there  any solution this topic?

Comment: Can you explain more on what you did and how you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: smartcard is a device which is local to the server, you can't install it to your server if it's not your local machine

Comment: I am preparing Demo. Only i want to use same machine. I mean Smart Card and IIS same machine. How can i solve this problem ?